# Angular routeProvider - unable to route with url param beyond root

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, url-parameters

My routes work fine for the most part. Calling `/:id` works perfectly and it'll load the right document from the API. However, i just added a new path for password resetting and i added `/reset/:id`. this throws an injector error and it'll show HTML in my js files, developer console shows it's trying to load the js files from an incorrect path as well.

I'm thinking i misconfigured something. Every other path works properly.

Core.js

```
angular.module("myApp", [ "ngRoute", 'wikiController', 'wikiServices' ])
.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled : true,
        requireBase : false
    });
})
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html",
        controller : "mainController",
        controllerAs : "app"
    })
    .when("/forgot", {
        templateUrl : "forgot.html",
        controller : "forgotController",
        controllerAs : "app"
    })
    .when("/reset/:token", {
        templateUrl : "reset.html",
        controller : "resetController",
        controllerAs : "app"
    })
    .when("/:id", {
        templateUrl : "module.html",
        controller : "moduleController",
        controllerAs : "app"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : 'main.html'
    })
})
```

index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<!-- ASSIGN OUR ANGULAR MODULE -->
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->
    <title>Anima Learning - Wiki</title>
    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <!-- load bootstrap -->
    <style>
        html {
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/core.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER AND GET ALL TODOS -->

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: routing file snippet?

Comment: since it it is two layer route maybe the js are not loading /something/something while the others are one layer route. can you put / ad the beginning of js files like /js/....

Comment: or give it an absolute address

Comment: @mast3rd3mon That's pretty much my routing file.

Comment: @Araz adding the / infront of the js paths causes a stack overflow :|
Seems it get's stuck in a loop somehow.

Comment: you have two routes with same patterns /:id and others with /something... can you change that route?

Comment: ist not ok to have /:id route

Comment: Actually adding the / infront of all the files in the index and a / infront of the templates seems to have fixed it after trying the same thing 3 times...